# ng-view: pass data from one view to another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

This is my first question to stackoverflow.com but I have been following it since days..

I am developing web application using nodejs with express framework and using node routing, I have done most of the work. But I ran into a problem these days that in client side I am using angularjs for two way data binding and other useful features of angularjs.

I need to make a client side routing with angularjs such that I have to pass some object ( contains users information) to another page on a button click ..
Whenever an admin clicks on the Register button, the page should redirect to a respective page(depending on the type of user) with the user information passed to another page that is automatically populated in the register form in the destination.

I have tried using services to communicate between controllers but on another page the data are either undefined or initialized NULL.

I would be very happy to get the answer that fits my solution

I can't post screenshot, coz no minimum reputation :((

Thanks in advance :))

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in `$rootscope` if the application is not refreshing while sending data from one view to another.

Example:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.test = "TEST";
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl2', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.value = $rootScope.test;
    alert($scope.value);
});
```

Comment: while working with views on angular, do we need to include scripts and css on the partials or are loaded by the parent view

Comment: It is loaded by parent view itself.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know how your app is built, but you could have your app maintain a kind of state configuration and then save information to common variables that these views share. Basically a one page app with the illusion of multiple pages. Look into Angular-UI.

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
  url: "/",
   views: {
    "viewONE": {
      controller: 'p1Controller',
      template: '<p>Some stuff</p>'
    },
    "viewTWO": {
      controller: 'p2Controller',
      template: '<span>Some more stuff</span>'
    },
    [AND SO ON]
  }
})
```

Comment: can i have some example tutorial on angular-ui ??